# Is there a container with dynamic size but no allocation in c++?

Tags: c++, containers

I'm programming C++ for embedded constraint devices.

I often have some memory on the stack or heap and need a container like a vector to access parts of it. For example when parsing some message with 20 bytes I want a container to access byte 5 to 10.

The container would need a start pointer, end pointer and must not allocate nor free memory. Is there something in c++ that helps me here?

vector allocates memory, array needs a fixed size which I do not know before.

Comment: Are you asking for a view type?

Comment: You can tell `std::vector` where to allocate memory from (see [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)). And if you have something like [`alloca`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca) available it will allocate on the stack.

Comment: Stack memory is usually allocated at compile time, based on the size of the local variables

Comment: If you dont know the size in advance to define an array, how do you know it for an vector? If can define a upper boundary, which you would liek to pass to an vector, then do the same for an array and store the number of used elements.

Comment: @Cristik the stack doesn't exist at compile time.

Comment: @manni66 I tried to say that the memory amount to be used on the stack is determined at compile time, so the size of a container like this will need to be known at compile time

Comment: I don't know of anything in standard c++ but there is [span](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span) in [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL).

Answer (score 5):

> For example when parsing some message with 20 bytes I want a container
>   to access byte 5 to 10.

I think you don't need any more containers for this. If the message is already stored in already allocated array all you need is a pair of iterators to memory range inside array. Now you can pass these iterators to some [stl algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) to perform the job you want or write your own.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking about returning this "pair of iterators" from a member function and like to avoid a call by reference signature. But maybe I'm heading in the wring direction.

Comment: You can return a [pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) of iterators by value.

Comment: Note that pointers into an array satisfy the concept `RandomAccessIterator` (and `OutputIterator`)

Comment: This pair of iterators is one kind of **range** - you can expect more support for ranges in C++20 and beyond.  For now, using a `std::pair` of iterators will give you something you can easily adapt to ranges when they are available to you.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a simple `view` type that has the same members as `std::array`, but without owning the underlying array. All of the members have obvious implementations

```
template <typename T>
struct view {
    using value_type             = T;
    using size_type              = std::size_t;
    using difference_type        = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using reference              = value_type&;
    using const_reference        = const value_type&;
    using pointer                = value_type*;
    using const_pointer          = const value_type*;
    using iterator               = value_type*;
    using const_iterator         = const value_type*;
    using reverse_iterator       = std::reverse_iterator<value_type*>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const value_type*>;

    view(pointer b = nullptr, pointer e = nullptr) : begin_(b), end_(e) {}
    template<size_type N>
    view(T (&arr)[N]) : begin_(arr), end_(arr + N) {}
    view(const view &) = default;
    view(view&&) = default;

    reference at(size_type i) { if (i < 0 || i > size()) throw std::out_of_range(); return *(begin_ + i); }
    const_reference at(size_type i) const { if (i < 0 || i > size()) throw std::out_of_range(); return *(begin_ + i); }

    reference operator[](size_type i) { return *(begin_ + i); }
    const_reference operator[](size_type i) const { return *(begin_ + i); }

    reference front() { return *begin_; }
    const_reference front() const { return *begin_; }

    reference back() { return *(end_ -1); }
    const_reference back() const { return *(end_ -1); }

    pointer data() { return begin_; }
    const_pointer data() const { return begin_; }

    iterator begin() { return begin_; }
    iterator end() { return end_; }

    const_iterator begin() const { return begin_; }
    const_iterator end() const { return end_; }

    const_iterator cbegin() const { return begin_; }
    const_iterator cend() const { return end_; }

    reverse_iterator rbegin() { return { begin_ }; }
    reverse_iterator rend() { return { end_ }; }

    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const { return { begin_ }; }
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const { return { end_ }; }

    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const { return { begin_ }; }
    const_reverse_iterator crend() const { return { end_ }; }

    bool empty() const { return begin_ == end_; }
    difference_type size() const { return end_ - begin_; }
    difference_type max_size() const { return std::numeric_limits<difference_type>::max() / sizeof(T); }

private:
    T * begin_, end_;
};
```

Comment: The related non-member functions are left as an exercise to the reader

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a container with dynamic size but no allocation in c++?

There is no such container in standard C++.

C99 does have variable length arrays and some C++ compilers provide that feature as a language extension.

---

> I often have some memory ... and need a container like a vector to access parts of it.

You don't need a container like a vector to access parts of memory. You can access memory directly. Example:

```
char c;
char* = memory_address;
c = memory_address[0]; // read access
memory_address[0] = c; // write access
```